# Alpha Conversion In Simple Type Theory

Tags: type-theory, lambda-calculus

I would like some help choosing rules expressing that terms with an $\alpha$ conversion between them should be considered equal. I am trying to setup a typed lambda calculus with sums like in

[Extensional Normalisation and Type-Directed Partial Evaluation for Typed Lambda Calculus with Sums](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Empf23/papers/Types/tdpe.pdf)

Except I am trying to explicitly express everything using inference rules.

$\alpha$ conversion is required for the two kinds of terms in the theory with bound expressions. For lambda abstractions I guess the $\alpha$ conversion rule should be

$$\begin{array}{c}
\underline{\Gamma,x:A\vdash b:B\hspace{1em}\Gamma,y:A\vdash b':B\hspace{1em}\Gamma\vdash b\left[y/x\right]\equiv b':B}\\
\Gamma\vdash\left(\lambda x:A\right).b\equiv\left(\lambda y:A\right).b':A\rightarrow B
\end{array}$$

where $y$ is free for $x$ in $b.$

For the terms $\text{match}\left(s,x.u,y.v\right)$ associated with sum types, as described in

[sum type, ncatlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/sum+type)

I guess that the corresponding rules for $\alpha$ conversion should be

$\begin{array}{c}
\underline{\Gamma\vdash s:A+B\hspace{1em}\Gamma,x:A\vdash u:C\hspace{1em}\Gamma,y:B\vdash v:C\hspace{1em}\Gamma,x':A\vdash u':C\hspace{1em}\Gamma\vdash u\left[x'/x\right]\equiv u':C}\\
\Gamma\vdash\text{match}\left(s,x.u,y.v\right)\equiv\text{match}\left(s,x'.u',y.v\right) : C
\end{array}$

(where $x'$ is free for $x$ in $u$)

and

\begin{array}{c}
\underline{\Gamma\vdash s:A+B\hspace{1em}\Gamma,x:A\vdash u:C\hspace{1em}\Gamma,y:B\vdash v:C\hspace{1em}\Gamma,y':B\vdash v':C\hspace{1em}\Gamma\vdash v\left[y'/y\right]\equiv v':C}\\
\Gamma\vdash\text{match}\left(s,x.u,y.v\right)\equiv\text{match}\left(s,x.u,y'.v'\right) : C
\end{array}

(where $y'$ is free for $y$ in $v$).

Here, for a term $u,$ and a variable $x$ and a term $a,$ of the same type as $x,$ we write $u\left[a/x\right]$ to denote the result of taking term $u$ and replacing all free occurrences of $x$ with term $a.$ If no free variables of $a$ become bound in $u\left[a/x\right]$ then we say $a$ is free for $x$ in $u.$

My issue is that I am not sure if my guesses about how to formalize equality of $\alpha$ convertible terms are correct, and so I would appreciate it if somebody could tell me if I am correct, or say which rules I should use.

Comment: Your ideas look correct to me, but, the devil is in the detail: you have to formalise your substitution operator $b \mapsto b[y/x]$, and, if your rules have no side-conditions, then substitution will need to rename bound variables (i.e., to do $\alpha$-conversions). Alternatively, you need a side condition that $y$ is free for $x$ in $b$ (so that $\alpha$-conversions have to work from the bottom up).

Comment: Possibly a more common approach is to define $\alpha$-equality of raw terms and then define the typing judgments on $\alpha$-equivalences classes (although written using particular representatives thereof).  Although an even more common approach is to use a representation like de Bruijn indices or locally nameless terms that avoids the issue entirely.  There's a reason those representations were invented; getting explicit $\alpha$-equivalence right formally is _really_ annoying.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. I have been looking up de Brujin indices and they do look like they make things much easier.